# Android Image file doesn't show

Tags: android, apk

I am developing an Android app.

It has so many local image files in R.drawables. (up to 2,000 .png files)

Yes, I need them all.

And when I develop the app, it shows all of the images correctly.

But when I make "aab/apk", many of them don't appear on the screen.

So I checked the "aab/apk".

[image]

Many images' size is 67B.
And just a black dot. (1x1 png)

What happen???

In debug mode, it works fine!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That might be the result of removing resources detected as unused, a.k.a. "shrink resources": https://developer.android.com/studio/build/shrink-code#shrink-resources

With `shrinkResources true`, I believe that the resources that are detected as unused are replaced with 1x1px images.

The link above also mentions how you can specify which images can be marked as necessary for the cases where the automated detection fails.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to show all the images at the same time, there might be memory issue in some devices with less memory. Try to downscale the images before showing them manually or using some third-party libraries like glide, picasso.

https://github.com/square/picasso

https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/graphics/load-bitmap